# Contar hombre y mujeres en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Quiero contar cuántos mujeres y hombres hay en cierta tabla agrupados por un campo llamado `SECCION`.

Mi tabla tiene una estructura como esta:

```
+---------+
|  DATOS  |
+=========+
| SECCION |
+---------+
| NOMBRE  |
+---------+
| SEXO    |
+---------+
| LISTA   |
+---------+
```

En `SEXO` solo hay dos valores posibles: `H` para hombre y `M` para mujer.
En `LISTA` solo hay dos valores posibles: `0` y `1`.

Pero solo sé hacer la consulta con una sola cuenta:

```
SELECT a.SECCION, COUNT(A.NOMBRE)
FROM DATOS a
GROUP BY a.SECCION
ORDER BY 1
```

Yo quisiera obtener como salida algo como esto:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| seccion | H y L=0 | H y L=1 | M y L=0 | M y L=1 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tengo forma de probar la consulta en estos momentos, pero debería quedar de la siguiente forma. Básicamente, sólo estará contando cuando se cumplan las dos condiciones, de otra forma sería un nulo y las funciones de agregado lo ignoran.

```
SELECT a.SECCION, 
    COUNT( CASE WHEN a.SEXO = 'H' AND LISTA = 0 THEN 1 END), 
    COUNT( CASE WHEN a.SEXO = 'H' AND LISTA = 1 THEN 1 END), 
    COUNT( CASE WHEN a.SEXO = 'M' AND LISTA = 0 THEN 1 END), 
    COUNT( CASE WHEN a.SEXO = 'M' AND LISTA = 1 THEN 1 END)
FROM DATOS a
GROUP BY a.SECCION
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: gracias, la pruebo enseguida.

Comment: Funcionó perfecto. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Y comprendiste por qué funcionó?

Comment: Por supuesto. La tabla con la que trabajé ni siquiera se parece al ejemplo que puse.